# How to fetch data from postgresql using QLineEdit text() into QtableWidgit

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qlineedit

I'm trying to fetch data from postgreSQL using if statement into `QTableWidget`, however when I'm applying variable and assigning null value(none), there is nothing showing in my table. And I cannot use where clause with `QlineEdit`. Is there any possible way to reproduce this code so it works properly?

```
def LoadData(self):
    name = self.Name_search.text()
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database = "postgres",
            user = "postgres",
            password = "**********",
            host = "localhost",
            port = "5432"
            ) 
    if name is None:
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        rows = cur.execute("Select * from swimming_pool_users where name = '%s'",(name))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        for row in data:
            self.AddTable(row)
        cur.close()
        
def AddTable(self,columns):
    rowPosition = self.tableWidget2.rowCount()
    self.tableWidget2.insertRow(rowPosition)
    for i, column in enumerate(columns):
        self.tableWidget2.setItem(rowPosition, i, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(column)))
def ClearTableData (self):
    while (self.tableWidget2.rowCount() > 0):
        self.tableWidget2.removeRow(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand what do you want exactly, but this is an example of how to show data from postgresql database to a QtableWidgit

```
def exemple_Qtablewidgit(self):
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                               password="password",
                               host="localhost",
                               database="database")
        self.cur = connection.cursor()

        name = self.lineEdit.text()

        self.cur.execute(''' SELECT * FROM exemple WHERE name =%s''', (name,))
        data = self.cur.fetchall()

        if data :
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

            self.tableWidget.insertRow(0)
            for row, form in enumerate(data):
                for column , item in enumerate(form):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))
                    column += 1 

                row_position  = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
                self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(row_position)
```